# JavaScript .find returning undefined in Angular Observable service

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm mocking out some data and for the life of me, the simple thing of the javascript .find method is returning undefined.

```
USERS: IUserDetail[] = 
  [
      {
        id: 1,
        firstName: 'Greg',
        lastName: 'Smith',
        email: 'gsmith@gmail.com',
        phone: '111-222-3333',
        company: 'ABC Corp, Inc.',
        country: 'United States of America',
        city: 'New York',
        jobRole: 'Chief Financial Officer',
        accountType: 'Individual'
      }
  ]

  getUserById(userId: number): Observable<IUserDetail> {
    console.log(userId) // returning 1
    console.log(this.USERS.find(x => x.id === userId)) // returning undefined
    return of(this.USERS.find(x => x.id === userId));
  }
```

Comment: Do a log for `x`. See if the equal check is correct.

Comment: needed double equals not triple.

Comment: If id is a value, shouldn't triple equals work? You should double check the comparison.